# Checking effective permissions with boost::filesystem / std::filesystem

Tags: permissions, stat, boost-filesystem, directory-permissions

So, `boost::filesystem` lets you access a file's permissions in the sense of which permissions the owner has, which permissions the group has and which all users have. That's nice, but I don't want to start checking who I am, what my group is etc - I just want to check if I can, say, recurse some directory or not (and not by trying to do so and failing). How should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if boost::filesystem has that feature, but POSIX has [`access(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/access).